# Растянуть SVG-изображение с изменением пропорций внутри CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, svg

Хотел бы достичь такого эффекта: фигурная скобка растягивается на неизвестную заранее суммарную высоту желтого и синего блока (изображение ниже отрисовано в графическом редакторе).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уточню, что это нужно не для формул, а для инфографики.

Насколько мне известно, в CSS нет механизма адаптивного растягивая символов, но вероятно, SVG поможет достичь такого эффекта. Концептуально, я собираюсь создать SVG-рисунок в HTML-коде, добавить туда текстовый элемент с фигурной скобкой, а дальше это изображение можно будет растянуть как элемент CSS Grid. Естественно, что в данном случае допускается нарушение пропорций изображения, правда меняться будет в основном высота.

```css
.Layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.Block1 {
  height: 60px;
  background: #FFA726;
}

.Block2 {
  height: 40px;
  background: #3F51B5;
}

.Image {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="Layout">
  <div class="Block1"></div>
  <svg class="Image">
    <text x="0" y="0"> { </text>
  </svg>
  <div class="Block2"></div>
</div>
```

Опыта с SVG у меня пока мало, а потому даже не знаю, как центрировать скобку посередине холста и на данный момент черновой код даёт такое отображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ничего страшного, я Вам благодарен уже за то, что Вы прочитали этот вопрос и готовы хотя бы попытаться помочь.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а почему это так сложно? Вроде как SVG на то рассчитан, чтобы его растягивать и сжимать.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT И какие же ограничения накладывает HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот код на базе вашего примера.

Обратите внимание, что высота блока Layout указана 1px. Это сделано из за особенностей свойства height в процентах. Если высота внешнего блока (блок Layout) вычисляется по содержимому, то высота в процентах (для блока Image) не работает, и заменится на height:auto.

Также обратите внимание на атрибут preserveAspectRatio в svg. Он используется для того, чтобы работало искажение (о котором вы говорите в вопросе). Если искажение вам не нужно, просто уберите этот атрибут и уберите значение width: 30px в стилях.

```css
.Layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  height: 1px;
}

.Block1 {
  height: 60px;
  background: #FFA726;
}

.Block2 {
  height: 40px;
  background: #3F51B5;
}

.Image {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.Image svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Layout">
  <div class="Block1"></div>
  <div class="Image">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 30 100">
        <text y="76" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="100">{</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="Block2"></div>
</div>
```

ps: вы можете поиграться со значением Y в теге svg>text для смещения скобки вверх/вниз.

Comment: @Sevastopol' ТС указал, что пропорциональность может страдать, но указал, что меняется в основном высота

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Посмотрел Ваше решение. Прошу меня простить, но ради качества Вашего ответа я обязан указать на обнаруженные недостатки Вашего в целом замечательного решения. 1) Попробовал убрать `height: 1px` - ничего не изменилось. Может оно не нужно? 2) Скобка видна лишь частично. С этим надо что-то сделать. 3) Координата y=76 указана жестко. Есть ли способ указать её относительно со смыслом "посередине"?

Comment: 1) Очень странно, что удаление height: 1px ничего не меняет. Это ключевой момент. Подробное объяснение здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/height-percent . 2) Ширина скобки задается свойством width в селекторе .Image svg. По идее вы можете подобрать подходящее для вас. 3) Координата y=76 указана жестко и это ровно середина скобки для используемого шрифта. Для разных шрифтов и символов "посередине" имеет разное значение. Потому что видимая часть символа НЕ равна глифу. Более подробно здесь https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#GlyphsMetrics

Comment: @Sevastopol, Вы имеете ввиду заменить элемент `text` на `path` или что-то ещё? Если да, то я не против, вопрос лишь в том, насколько сложно будет настроить все безье, особенно посередине скобки.

Comment: Принял решение сделать Вас победителем конкурса. Ваше решение отвечает на указанный в заголовке вопрос. Несмотря на наличие указанных выше проблем, Ваше решение обосновано и Вы представили ссылки на авторитетные источники данных. Думаю, эта работа заслуживает приза.

Answer (score 1):

Ни на что не претендую. Просто вот вам вариант изображения скобки на CSS.

Использование символа в качестве скобки, учитывая, что он должен адаптивно растягиваться, не считаю разумным. Как минимум потому, что один и тот же шрифт, у вас и у меня, может отображаться по-разному.

Если изобразить скобку в виде рисунка SVG, то такой вариант допустить можно. Однако, в этом случае тогда рисунок будет ни как одно целое, а состоять из нескольких элементов. Ну и здесь, как мне кажется на первый взгляд, могут возникнуть определенные трудности при растягивании линий. На мой взгляд, это решение не совсем рациональное.

Вариант ниже полностью решает поставленную задачу и исключает все ошибки при отображении.

```js
//Это вам не нужно
var range1 = document.querySelector('#range1'); var range2 = document.querySelector('#range2'); var range3 = document.querySelector('#range3'); var layout = document.querySelector('.Layout'); var block1 = document.querySelector('.Block1'); var block2 = document.querySelector('.Block2');
range1.addEventListener('input', function() {layout.style.width = this.value + '%';}, false); range2.addEventListener('input', function() {block1.style.height = this.value + 'px';}, false); range3.addEventListener('input', function() {block2.style.height = this.value + 'px';}, false);
```

```css
.Layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.Block1 {
  height: 60px;
  background: #FFA726;
}

.Block2 {
  height: 40px;
  background: #3F51B5;
}

.Image {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  height: 100%;
}

/*Скобка*/
.brace {
  position: relative; width: 14px; height: 100%; margin-left: 16px;
}

.brace>div:nth-child(1), .brace>div:nth-child(2) {
  box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0;
  width: 14px; height: calc(50% - 14px);
  border-left: 2px solid black; border-radius: 8px;
}
.brace>div:nth-child(1) { top: 0; border-top: 2px solid black; border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;}
.brace>div:nth-child(2) {bottom: 0; border-bottom: 2px solid black; border-radius: 0 0 0 8px;}

.brace>div:nth-child(3)::before, .brace>div:nth-child(3)::after {
  content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; left: -14px;
  width: 14px; height: 14px; border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.brace>div:nth-child(3)::before {
  top: calc(50% - 14px); border-bottom: 2px solid black; border-radius: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.brace>div:nth-child(3)::after {
  top: 50%; border-top: 2px solid black; border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

```html
Layout <input type="range" min="10" max="100" id="range1" value="100">
Block1 <input type="range" min="60" max="180" id="range2" value="1">
Block1<input type="range" min="40" max="120" id="range3" value="1">
<!--То что выше, вам не нужно-->

<div class="Layout">
  <div class="Block1"></div>
  <div class="Image">
<!--Скобка--><div class="brace"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение! Оно рабочее, и конкретно в моём случае оно подходит. К сожалению, ввиду того что другие пользователи, пришедшие по запросу "растянуть SVG" могут для себя решения не найти - у них может быть что-то посложнее, чем скобка. Поэтому я Вашему ответу плюсик поставлю и объявлю что, решение актуально конкретно для моего случая.